# Calling Python from R - assign variable string with double quotes

Tags: python, r, escaping

I wrote a Python function which allows me to repeat my command on all files in any folder:

```
import os

def removeChar(stringVar,removeChars):
    for znaki in removeChars:
        stringVar=stringVar.replace(znaki,'')
    return stringVar

def ForAllFiles(path,command='gdal2xyz.py "inputFile" "outputFile"',removeChars=[],extension='.tif',newExtension='.txt'):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        dirs.sort()
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extension):
                newFile=removeChar(file,removeChars)
                newFile=newFile.replace(extension,newExtension)
                cmd=command.replace('inputFile',os.path.join(root,file))
                cmd=cmd.replace('outputFile',os.path.join(root,newFile))
                os.system(cmd)
```

I wish to assign some Python variables (path, command) in R! and then execute this function from R!
One of the mentioned variables, contains command with file name ('inputFile'), so I wish to surround file name with double quotes.

When I call:

```
library(rPython)
python.assign("variable",'my "variable"')
```

I received an error:

wpython.exec(python.command) : 
  Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 9 (char 8)

So I thought that it will be enough to escape double quote:

```
python.assign("variable",'my \"variable\"')
python.assign("variable","my \"variable\"")
```

but it also doesn't work and produce error message

So my last idea was:

```
python.assign("variable","my " + python.exec("chr(34)") + "variable" + python.exec("chr(34)"))
```

but it also fails

Comment: Have you tried that Python code? It clearly has errors.

Comment: @pacholik You were right - I forgot that I defined additional function 'removeChar' in my Python script. I insered it - sorry for that.

Comment: @pacholik I tested - if you copy and paste my script to Python and define at least path and command, it will work properly (for example: command='ls "inputFile"' and then ForAllFiles(path, command) ).